# newest rvm won't display requirements

Tags: rvm

So I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but is there a particular setting for autolibs to have

```
rvm requirements
```

display the requirements instead of checking if they are installed? Or am I missing some other option to simply display requirements? I'm using version 1.19.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs - there are two modes that will be useful for you:

1. `rvm autolibs read-only` - it will do all the steps and only show the required commands / missing libraries
2. `rvm autolibs enable` - it will install everything for you, it might require sudo password so a nice trick for tools like capistranos is to:

   ```
   rvm autolibs read-only
   sudo rvm --autolibs=enabled requirements ruby-2.0.0
   rvm install ruby-2.0.0
   ```

A writeup about autolibs https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/rvm-ruby-2-0

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned I mean after I installed something it would be nice to see all the requirements as a recap to look back on. Or give a rundown of what I already had installed. I didn't realize I could pass something to requirements though!

Comment: It's no more possible to simply show the requirements as the code to find missing dependencies is highly dynamic, it would require implementing extra layer of complexity just to show them ... although RVM2 most likely will have that option.

Comment: Thanks for the additional followup!